# How do I keep the sea from flooding my basement?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I made my house on an island. I'm planning to build a basement, which requires the bottom of the house to be dug up.  While digging, if I decide my basement is too small and forget that I built my house on an island, it could flood the basement completely.  How would I be able to stop the flood and drain the remaining water quickly?

I am playing on SMP so someone else might *accidentally* flood my house.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you break a block and water flows in, it cannot create water inside the basement. It only allows water to flow in, this means it will only flow 7 blocks and if you replace the block you removed it will automatically drain.

This will revert it to as it was before it was flooded except that torches and redstone are uprooted and must be picked up and replaced, and levers are destroyed. Fire is also put out and lava turned to cobblestone/obsidian.

Comment: Torches, redstone and levers are not destroyed are they? I'm pretty sure they are just removed from where placed and you can gather them back up., i.e. a torch would knocked off a wall and would remain until it despawns.

Comment: That is true for torches yes, I ought to reword that. But levers are actually removed completely. I'm pretty sure it's a bug.

Answer (score 12):

Water cannot pass through signs, ladders and other non-solid, waterproof blocks. I recommend signs, you can stack them and build a wall this way.

Some servers might also have sponges enabled, ask the admin for that.

Comment: In case you already have a hole, putting a sign in the hole will stop the flood and, due to the Minecraft Water Physics, everything will dry very quickly.

Comment: Last I checked, signs don't stack.  Ladders do, and are *somewhat* cheaper, by 2 sticks.  Ladders also avoid the need to enter text (or hit 'ok' to leave a sign blank)

Comment: @thedaian — I believe he's referring to the ability to place signs "on" each other in the game world (leaving them apparently unsupported) rather than stacking them in your inventory.